# Automation of Grouping Dates Weekly

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I start out with an excel spreadsheet that looks like this;

[image]

I then manually set column widths and change the alignment of the header row so eventually I get something like this (I also apply conditional formatting to the 1's;

[image]

The issue is that this takes a considerable amount of time (especially for months at a time) and automating the process would be very useful. Is there a way I can achieve something like this without doing it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can write a macro.

A good starting point is to

1. start the Excel macro recorder,
2. execute all the actions manually, and
3. stop the recorder.

You will then have a working macro that does exactly what you want in further Excel sheets.

You can then open the macro (ALT+F11) and review the code, and with even basic knowledge of programming, will be able to understand and do minor changes if needed.